# Accessing the output from module via index

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create 2 VMs on Azure using Terraform.

I create 2 NICs like

```
variable "internalips" {
  description = "List of Internal IPs"
  default = ["10.0.2.10", "10.0.2.11"]
  type = "list"
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "helloterraformnic" {
count = 2
name = "nic-${count.index}"
location = "West US"
resource_group_name = "myrg"

    ip_configuration {
        name = "testconfiguration1"
        subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.helloterraformsubnet.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
        private_ip_address = "${element(private_ip_address, count.index)}"
    }
}
```

Now I want to use them in module azurerm_virtual_machine

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "helloterraformvm" {
    count = 2
    name = "${element(elasticmachines, count.index)}"
    location = "West US"
    resource_group_name = "myrg"
    network_interface_ids = "${element(azurerm_network_interface.helloterraformnic, count.index)}"
....
}
```

This gives me an error

> Failed to load root config module: Error loading azure/rg.tf: Error
>   reading config for azurerm_virtual_machine[helloterraformvm]:
>   azurerm_network_interface.helloterraformnic: resource variables must
>   be three parts: TYPE.NAME.ATTR in:
>
> ${element(azurerm_network_interface.helloterraformnic, count.index)}

How can I use the above created NICs using index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thinking to use `length` function to get the counts more than hard coding it.

from

```
count = 2
```

change to

```
count = "${length(var.internalips)}"
```

For your problem, you need to tell the resource which attribute you want to get the value.

```
network_interface_ids = "${element(azurerm_network_interface.helloterraformnic.id, count.index)}"
```

Refer:

[terraform Interpolation Syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html)

[terraform azurerm_virtual_machine Attributes Reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_interface.html#attributes-reference)